# C# DateTime.ToString "o" Format Returns Different String on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, datetime, iso8601

I have a scenario in which I want to turn UTC dates into ISO 8601 strings with a certain timezone to send down via web api. The recommended way to do this is to use TimeZoneInfo like so:

```
var configuredTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneString);
var localTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, configuredTimeZone), DateTimeKind.Local);
var stringResult = localTime.ToString("o");
```

This works fine on my local machine, but I'm running into a very weird situation where ToString outputs a different string when the code is hosted in an Azure web app. Locally I get 2017-02-20T00:00:00-06:00 (which is what I want, as it contains the timezone info I need), but when hosted in Azure I get 2017-02-20T00:00:00+00:00.(which is in UTC, not what I want). Since I am manually applying the time zone I want, I am not sure why the format is appending the wrong timezone information. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: `DateTime` cannot store a time zone.

Comment: and the *local* timezone in Azure is UTC.

Comment: I'm manually providing the timezone I want via TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc, so how would Azure's use of UTC  mess up the conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, `System.DateTime` cannot store time zones. All it knows is "local" or "UTC". Being hosted in Azure, its "local" time **is** UTC.

So your statement of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, configuredTimeZone)` would convert the UTC time to *your* time (midnight of the 20th), but because `DateTime` holds no timezone, it is of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. Your `DateTime.SpecifyKind(...,  DateTimeKind.Local)` simply tells it that it is of type "local", and in the case of an Azure host, UTC+00:00.

If timezones are important, you want to utilise [System.DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx#Remarks) instead of `DateTime`. It is specifically built for holding and manipulating (as its name implies) timezone offsets.